# A Steel post and base question

Tags: steel, structures

I make solid curved wood furniture and frequently need something like a metal plate (1/8") with a (3/4" about) supporting pipe attached at 90 degrees. Welding is a little too cumbersome but I was wondering if you guys out there know about any connecting solutions similar to a concrete anchor setup?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just thread the inside of the pipe / tube and use an ordinary bolt.

Make sure the pipe / tube is thick enough not to fail after threading.

Based on a comment, a cheaper variation that is commonly used is to crimp a nut into the tube - as long as the force required is low compared to the de-crimping force...

Comment: Depending on the strength of the joint & fixing required, a variation of this would be to fix a nut into, or to the end of the tube & then use a narrower diameter bolt

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a miracle connector to take a little less time but it sounds like it doesn't exist. Will go back to plan A. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried using the concrete bolt ?  There are some expansion bolts used in the wall of tube steels but this is slightly different in application

Comment: Thread the end of the pipe and tighten from below. The hardware store usually can make that thread for you. It's better than bring the parts to a welding shop if you can't do it yourself.

Comment: Thread the outside of the pipe and make a threaded hole in the plate.  Screw the pipe directly to the plate is another option

Comment: @ForwardEd so minimum depth of thread should be approx the diamter - so the thread in the plate won't be too strong... but you could nut either side with washers and/or weld nuts to the plate...